# Printing BST in pre order

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I am trying to print out my binary tree in pre order form however I am coming across these errors. I am still learning python so I am not quite sure what is going on. But I assume that my print function isn't working properly. Not quite sure why preorder_print is having a global name issue though =/

Output:

```
>>> from BST_tree import *
pre order:
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0C88>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from BST_tree import *
  File "BST_tree.py", line 51, in <module>
    preorder_print(r)
  File "BST_tree.py", line 27, in preorder_print
    preoder_print(root.left)
NameError: global name 'preoder_print' is not defined
```

my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value


def BST_Insert(root, node):     # root --> root of tree or subtree!
    if root.value is None:
        root = node             # beginning of tree
    else:
        if root.value > node.value:     # go to left
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.left, node)
        else:
            if root.value < node.value:    # go to right      
                root.right = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.right, node)


def preorder_print(root):
    print root
    if root.left is not None:
        preoder_print(root.left)
    else:
        if root.right is not None:
            preorder_print(root.right)


r = Node(4)
# left
a = Node(2)
b = Node(1)
c = Node(3)
# right
d = Node(8)
e = Node(6)
f = Node(10)

BST_Insert(r, a)
BST_Insert(r, b)
BST_Insert(r, c)
BST_Insert(r, d)
BST_Insert(r, e)
BST_Insert(r, f)

print "pre order:"
preorder_print(r)
```

Comment: This really is a separate problem from your original problem, and it's better to create a new question instead of to keep editing the same question until everything gets fixed.

Comment: Yes it is sorry but the typo error you pointed out fixed all the errors and now the only problem is my print function. I guess i can create another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple typo: you defined `preorder_print`, but tried to call `preoder_print`.

When you see an error message like this:

```
NameError: global name 'preoder_print' is not defined
```

… don't worry so much about the "global" part. The problem is that the name isn't defined *anywhere*, not even in the globals.* So, start looking for why it isn't defined.

Typos like this are very easy to make, so that's usually the first thing I check: Copy the string from the error message, then paste it into a search.

---

* This is a bit oversimplified, but good enough for now. What it *actually* means is that first the compiler couldn't find it as a local or closure name at compile time, and so assumed it's a global name, and then the interpreter couldn't find it as a global or builtin at runtime.

Comment: thank you that clearly removed all the errors! However, my logic is incorrect now =/ I inserted root and 6 other nodes but the print only displays 3 pieces of code i do not understand. Probably location of each object.pre order:
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0988>
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0E08>
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0E88>

Comment: @Liondancer: I'm not sure I understand your new problem. Is it just that you want these printed out in some nicer format, e.g., `Node(4)`? If you want that, you either need to explicitly print what you want instead of just printing the object itself, or you need to give the object a `__repr__` method.

Comment: I edited the question to work around the printing problem I am having. Thank you for pointing out that typo! much appreciated!