# Print BST in pre order

Tags: python, python-2.7

rI am trying to print out my binary tree in pre order form however I am coming across these errors. I am still learning python so I am not quite sure what is going on. But I assume that my print function isn't working properly. Not quite sure why preorder_print is having a global name issue though =/

my expected output would be

```
pre order:
4
2
1
3
8
6
10
```

Output:

```
pre order:
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0988>
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0E08>
<BST_tree.Node instance at 0x0000000002AA0E88>
```

my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value


def BST_Insert(root, node):     # root --> root of tree or subtree!
    if root.value is None:
        root = node             # beginning of tree
    else:
        if root.value > node.value:     # go to left
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.left, node)
        else:
            if root.value < node.value:    # go to right      
                root.right = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.right, node)


def preorder_print(root):
    print root
    if root.left is not None:
        preorder_print(root.left)
    else:
        if root.right is not None:
            preorder_print(root.right)


r = Node(4)
# left
a = Node(2)
b = Node(1)
c = Node(3)
# right
d = Node(8)
e = Node(6)
f = Node(10)

BST_Insert(r, a)
BST_Insert(r, b)
BST_Insert(r, c)
BST_Insert(r, d)
BST_Insert(r, e)
BST_Insert(r, f)

print "pre order:"
preorder_print(r)
```

*** EDIT ***

Thank you everyone and especially  **abarnert**  for your help!!! Here is the fixed version! or the preorder_print and BST_Inert

```
def BST_Insert(root, node):     # root --> root of tree or subtree!
    if root.value is None:
        root = node             # beginning of tree
    else:
        if root.value > node.value:     # go to left
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.left, node)

        if root.value < node.value:    # go to right
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.right, node)


def preorder_print(root):
    print root.value
    if root.left is not None:
        preorder_print(root.left)
    if root.right is not None:
        preorder_print(root.right)
```

Comment: Hold on, is your problem the way the nodes are printing out, or the fact that you're only getting 3 instead of 6? (Also, the code you posted here still has the same typo from [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170285/printing-bst-in-pre-order), so nobody can test it to help you debug your problem.)

Comment: shoot but it is actually both

Comment: It really helps to ask one question at a time. Many people will race to answer one problem, and then leave, and you'll be stuck with half your problems unsolved. On top of that, if someone else has a similar problem in the future, he won't be able to find your nicely-answered question in a search, because it will look like a question about something unrelated to his problem. The Help has more information on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for posting two answers, but I'm not sure which of two problems you're asking about here.

Your preorder traversal isn't covering the entire tree, because you ignore the entire right subtree whenever the left subtree isn't empty:

```
def preorder_print(root):
    print root
    if root.left is not None:
        preoder_print(root.left)
    else:
        if root.right is not None:
            preorder_print(root.right)
```

So, in your example, because the `4` node has the `2` node on its left, it won't look at `8` or anything underneath it. And then the same thing in the `2`. So, you only get 3 nodes instead of all 7.

To fix this, just remove the `else`:

```
def preorder_print(root):
    print root
    if root.left is not None:
        preoder_print(root.left)
    if root.right is not None:
        preorder_print(root.right)
```

---

You also have a problem in your `BST_Insert` function. You're setting `root.right = node` any time `node.value > root.value`, even if there's already something there. So, the first time you try to insert something that's on the left side of the right side of anything, it will erase the parent—the `6` erases the `8`, then the `10` erases the `6`, so you end up with just 4, 2, 1, 3, and 10.

I think what you wanted here is to change this:

```
    else:
        if root.value < node.value:    # go to right      
            root.right = node
        else:
            BST_Insert(root.right, node)
```

… to:

```
    elif root.value < node.value:    # go to right     
        if root.right is None
            root.right = node
        else:
            BST_Insert(root.right, node)
```

Comment: wow thanks! that help! however the output is now 4,2,1,3,10. it seemd to have skipped 2 nodes on the right side of the node and went for the fartest right node

Comment: Ah, your `BST_Insert` is overwriting nodes on the right. You do `root.right = node` even though `root.right` already exists. What did you want to do instead?

Comment: Actually, your help in the preorder_print function helped me figure out that my BST_Insert was going through the tree in correctly. The logic was wrong in that but I fixed it! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Liondancer: Glad you found it and fixed it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

The print function is working just fine. When you print out an object that doesn't have a custom `__repr__` or `__str__` method, this is exactly what you're supposed to get.

There are two ways to solve this.

---

First, instead of printing the `Node` object itself, print the information you want to print. For example, change this:

```
print root
```

… to:

```
print 'node with value {}'.format(root.value)
```

… or:

```
print root.value
```

… or:

```
print 'I've got a node and he's got a value and it's ' + str(root.value)
```

---

Alternatively, if you always want nodes to print out the same way—e.g., `Node(4)`—you can give the class a `__repr__` method:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Node({})'.format(self.value)
```

---

Sometimes you want to provide both a nice human-readable representation of a class that you might put into a report, and a different representation that's useful for, e.g., experimenting at the interactive interpreter. In that case, you define both `__str__` and `__repr__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    # Pick whatever you think looks nice here
    return str(self.value)
    # return 'Node: ' + str(self.value)
    # return 'Node with value {}'.format(self.value)

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Node({})'.format(self.value)
```

(Notice that `Node(4)` is a nice "experimenting at the interactive interpreter" representation, because it's exactly what you'd type into the interpreter to create an equivalent object.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `print root.value` instead of `print root`.

Explanation:
`root` is an object, an instance of the `Node` class. `root.value` is the actual number the node holds.

Aside: the "proper" way to do this would be what @abarnert answered, via `__repr__`, but it's a little overkill for simple exercises focused around teaching about trees.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print the value of root

```
print root.value
```